# How to duplicate a product page

Tags: plugins

I have a product section in Wordpress. I want to duplicate of of my products.

I looked for plugins and found several that allow me to do this for pages and posts but none to duplicate a product. What are the steps to do this?

Comment: How is your product section implemented? Are products sub-pages? A custom post type? Are you using an ECommerce plugin? **Note that plugin recommendations are offtopic on this site**

Comment: check vedio :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFt7tO3W8Tk

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must be using WooCommerce, WooCommerce products is a CPT e.g. posts, so a plugin like [Duplicate Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicate-post/) can duplicate your products as well.

Comment: I dont think i see woocommerce installed. Is there a way to check?

Comment: WooCommerce is a plugin, so you can check in your plugin list. But if you are not using WooCommerce then what is "products" that you refer in your original question. Is "products" a CPT (Custom Post Type)?